# how to input data into an array from a text file that are vbTab separated?

Tags: vb.net, file-io

I am having trouble turning a set of data from a .txt file into arrays, basically, what i have in the text file is:

```
Eddy vbtab 20
Andy vbtab 30 
James vbtab 20
```

etc..

I want to set up the names as a Names array, and numbers as number array.

Now what I have done is

```
strFilename = "CustomerPrices.txt"
If File.Exists(strFilename) Then
  Dim srReader As New StreamReader(strFilename)
  intRecords = srReader.ReadLine() 
  intRows = intRecords     

  For i = 0 To intRows - 1
    intLastBlank = strInput.IndexOf(vbTab)
    strName(intPrices) = strInput.Substring(0, intLastBlank)

    dblPrices(intPrices) = Double.Parse(strInput.Substring(intLastBlank + 1))
```

But when I debug I get a problem "Object Reference not set to an instance of an object"

Can anyone give me some advise?

Thanks

Comment: Joel gave you a solution below. The answer to your question about the debug problem is that you're using `strInput` without declaring it or assigning anything to it first. (You read a line of text into `intRecords`, which you never use, and then use `strInput` which doesn't exist. You also refer to `strName`, `intPrices`, and `dblPrices` that aren't declared anywhere in your code.)

Comment: @Kenwhite  hi ken, thanks for pointing that out, but I did declare all the necessary objects, I just didn't show it in the post. When debugging this code I received NullReferenceException was unhandled - "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: Your code shows them being used without an assignment. Even if you declared them elsewhere and didn't show it, they still need to have values assigned to them before they can be used - that's why you're getting the `NullReferenceException`. (And you should always post **complete** code when you're having a code-related issue, BTW. If you don't, your chances of getting a correct answer are much lower.)

Answer (score 3):

Separate arrays are probably a bad idea here. They group your data by fields, when it's almost always better to group your data by records.  What you want instead is a single collection filled with classes of a particular type.  Go for something like this:

```
Public Class CustomerPrice
   Public Property Name As String
   Public Property Price As Decimal
End Class

Public Function ReadCustomerPrices(ByVal fileName As String) As List(Of CustomerPrice)
    Dim result As New List(Of CustomerPrice)()
    Using srReader As New StreamReader(fileName)
        Dim line As String
        While (line = srReader.ReadLine()) <> Nothing
            Dim data() As String = line.Split(vbTab)
            result.Add(new CustomerPrice() From {Name = data(0), Price = Decimal.Parse(data(1))})
        End While
    End Using
    Return result
End Function
```

Some other things worth noting in this code:

- The Using block will guarantee the file is closed, even if an exception is thrown
- It's almost never appropriate to check File.Exists(). It's wasteful code, because you still have to be able to handle the file io exceptions.
- When working with money, you pretty much always want to use the Decimal type rather than Double
- This code requires Visual Studio 2010 / .Net 4, and was typed directly into the reply window and so likely contains a bug, or even base syntax error.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply, I will try it out!

Comment: Case in point about my last sentence: I just plain forgot the while loop at first